# Visual Basic: Message Box Prompt Twice When I Click On Button

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, messagebox

I have problem with my message box. This is part of app which check if serial number has already been used. If yes, it shows error message,when click YES program continues and make some functions, NO button end sub. It works well, but it shows me message box twice and I really don't understand why, please help

```
If File.Exists(pathSN) Then
    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(pathSN)

    If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
        Dim msg = "Serial number has already been used"
        Dim title = "Error"
        Dim style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or _
                    MsgBoxStyle.Critical
        Dim response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
        MsgBox(msg, style, title)

        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            wrlayout()
            openlayout()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You call MsgBox two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...
Dim response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
MsgBox(msg, style, title)
...`

you do not need the second call to `MsgBox`